# Macbook headphones disabled after inactivity in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, audio, boot-camp, headphones, macbook-pro-retina

Setup:

- Macbook Pro retina 2015 (force touch)
- Windows 10 installed through Boot Camp 6
- Cirrus Logic CS4208 (AB123) sound card, driver correctly installed

When I plug in my headphones, they are detected and sound is redirected to them. 
After a period of inactivity, when the monitor is turned off, the headphones stop, and the laptop's speaker becomes the default sound device. If I don't turn off the music when stepping away from my computer, often I find it playing in the speakers when I return instead of the headphones.
Cannot re-enable the headphones, only by pulling the plug and re-inserting it in the laptop. Really annoying.
Cannot find any power saving settings in windows for the headphones or the sound card.

How can I turn this timeout off?